# Buy 3 Get 1 Free discount not working when checking out with Paypal

Tags: php, woocommerce, paypal, discount

I'm currently trying to run a buy 3 get the cheapest free offer with the coupon code 'buy3onefree'. The code works apart from when the user tries to checkout using Paypal.

I've narrowed it down to issues with Paypal not working with negative fees which i've used to create the discount:

```php
$wc_cart->add_fee( $label, number_format( -$discount, 4 ), true, 'standard' );
```

Is there any alternative to using add_fee to create a discount?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any alternative to using add_fee to create a discount?

Consult the [documentation for WC_Cart](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Cart.html)